# node.js modify response and store request at the same time

Tags: node.js, json-server

So what I'm trying to do is to manualy overwrite response when there is a request to my json-server. I'm fine with that, but I dont know how to add a bit to also store the original request in database.

Here is my code (i'm sending as response the name from request and static uuid)
The next(); in if step is failing complaining it cannot setup headers.

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

    if (req.path == "/business") {
        res.status(201);

        res.jsonp({
            id: "a23e1b13-cf69-461c-aa8a-a0eb99e41350",
            name: req.body['name'],
            revision: "1"
        });

        next();
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from middleware to any routes you can assign value with req object rather than res object.

```
app.use(function(req.res)) {
    req.custom_data = {
            id: "a23e1b13-cf69-461c-aa8a-a0eb99e41350",
            name: req.body['name'],
            revision: "1"
        };
next();
}
```

From other location you can do like this.

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
res.jsonp(req.custom_data)//something like this
}
```

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

For example, we cannot:

*server.js*

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server")
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router("db.json")

server.use(jsonServer.defaults())
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.method === "POST" && req.url === "/business") {
    res.status(201)
    res.jsonp({
      id: "a23e1b13-cf69-461c-aa8a-a0eb99e41350",
      name: req.body["name"],
      revision: "1"
    })
  }
  next()
})

server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("JSON Server is running")
})
```

Or we get: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` when we run `node server.js`, because we have already set and sent the headers when we call `res.jsonp`, so we cannot do this again by calling `server.use(router)`.

We have a couple options.

Option 1.

*server.js*

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server")
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router("db.json")

server.use(jsonServer.defaults())

server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("JSON Server is running")
})
```

*db.json*

```
{
  "business": []
}
```

Now we can POST to our `http://localhost:3000/business` endpoint and save our request body to our database. However, we cannot amend the 201 status, nor the request body to something else.

Option 2.

*server.js*

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server")
const server = jsonServer.create()

server.use(jsonServer.defaults())
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)

server.post("/business", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(201)
  res.jsonp({
    id: "a23e1b13-cf69-461c-aa8a-a0eb99e41350",
    name: req.body["name"],
    revision: "1"
  })
  next()
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("JSON Server is running")
})
```

Now we get the correct response, but we can no longer save to our database `business` key, because we are calling `server.post("/business"...`

You could however use this in your own code and save it somewhere else (or write to your own database), as this response will be returned from a Promise.